# Docker postgres image: How to restrict access from host network?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm running a postgres server in a docker container within a custom docker network, and I found I can access it using `psql` from the host.

This seems to me to be undesirable from a security perspective since I thought the point of docker networks was to isolate access to the containers.

My thinking was that I would run my app in a separate container within the same docker network and publish ports on the app container only. That way, the app can be accessed from the outside world, but the database can't be.

My question is: Why is the 5432 port being published to host on the postgres container without me explicitly specifying that, and how can I "unpublish" this port?

And a related question would be: am I wrong that publishing port 5432 is a security concern in this case (or at least *less secure* than not publishing it)?

My container is running the official docker postgres image here: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

Thanks for any help!

Edit: Here is the docker command I'm using to run the container:

```
docker run -d --restart=always --name=db.geppapp.com -e "POSTGRES_USER=<user>" -e "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=<password>" -e "POSTGRES_DB=gepp" -v "/mnt/storage/postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data" --net=db postgres
```

Edit 2: My original question was not entirely correct as docker was not in fact publishing the port 5432 to the host but rather I was specifying the container's IP address as the host when connecting to postgres with `psql` as follows:

```
psql --host=<docker-assigned-ip> --username=<user> --dbname=gepp
```

So the thing preventing me from restricting access to the container from the host is in fact that an IP address is assigned to the container on the host network.

Comment: Are you starting the container with `docker run` or `docker-compose`? Please post the `docker run` command you use or the `docker-compose.yaml`

Comment: Edited the question to include the `docker run` command

Comment: How are you accessing the container using `psql`?  Can you access it from _other_ hosts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone who commented and answered. I'm answering my own question with a summary of my best understanding based on the replies and other things I've read.

As I mentioned in the edit to my question the thing preventing me from restricting access to the container from the host is the IP assignment on the host network.

According to the docker docs: (https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/)

> By default, the container is assigned an IP address for every Docker
> network it connects to.

In this case, the container is not technically "connected" to the host network but has an IP on that network anyway. David pointed out in comments that this only occurs on Linux, not on Windows or Mac (I haven't personally verified this).

So it would appear that due to the way docker networks are implemented in Docker Linux, an IP address is published to the host for all running containers, and there's no way to prevent this.

From a security perspective, since the docker host is always trusted, my understanding is that database security comes mainly from restricting access to the host itself (network and linux account security), and the native database credential security. Docker does not add another secure layer as I was initially thinking it might.

Answer (score 0):

The Dockerfile of postgres exposes that port 5432, but that does not mean it makes the port of the container accessible to the host.  To expose the port to host, you must use either the -p flag to publish a range of ports or the -P flag to publish all of the exposed ports. But I don't see that in your command.

Are you sure you are not accessing a local postgres and not the container postgres?

or Are you connected to the Host network? If docker container is set to network_mode: host or type of host, any port exposed in the container would be exposed on the docker host as well, without requiring the -p or -P docker run options.

Comment: All ports with services behind them are accessible from the host, no matter if they are EXPOSEd and mapped or not. You can find the IP address of the container and access the ports directly.

Comment: Now that you mention it, the `psql` command I'm using includes the docker-assigned ip address as host: `psql --host=<docker-assigned-ip> --username=<user> --dbname=gepp`. So given that, I guess my real question is how to stop docker from publishing an ip to the host network at all (and, is this even desirable?).

Comment: I ran the same command in my machine and was not able to access this via psql.  You are able to access this maybe via the network (--net=db) attached to the docker image.

Comment: If docker container is set to network_mode: host, then maybe you have to play around with the iptables. I am not sure if we can do it from the docker level.

Comment: @Hans Kilian do you know of a way to prevent docker from assigning an IP to the container on the host network?

Comment: It's worth noting that the IP address @HansKilian describes is only accessible on the same host, and only on native Linux; it's not accessible from off-host and this trick doesn't work on MacOS or Windows systems.  More specifically, the host is able to make a connection to the `docker0` network.  You can't really prevent this but it's also not really harmful.

Comment: @David Maze - thanks for your comment. I think you've more or less answered my question, but in fact the containers are on a custom network, not `docker0`. My idea was to completely isolate the containers on this network from the host (ie. so the host cannot even access them by ip). The origin of this idea is that if I were to, say, put the db server and backend app on separate AWS instances within a subnet, the db instance would have no public address but would only be accessible to the app via a private address within the subnet (or in this case, within the docker network).

Comment: If they're on separate instances, they won't be able to share a Docker network, unless you manually set up an overlay network.  But in that environment you can use an AWS VPC and security groups to protect the network setup.  (Also in that environment you could use a dedicated host for a non-Docker database, or use RDS for the database, while still running the application in Docker.)

Comment: @David Maze Thanks again for your comment. I think I wasn't being very clear before as I am actually not hosting things on different instances. I was just making an analogy of AWS instances on subnets as compared to docker containers on docker networks. My original question is about my desire to "hide" the database server inside the docker network (hidden from the host as well) in the same way that a database server can be "hidden" in a subnet from anything outside the subnet.